# Can I use Google analytics without setting up "data stream"?

Tags: google-analytics, data-stream, cookieconsent

Can I use Google analytics without setting up "data stream"? or is it required to use? Actually, Google analytics keeps showing this warning/error in Google analytics.

In case, I use it. Would it be enough to explain in cookie consent that we are using Google analytics and storing cookies? Or I have to specify about the data stream?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the new GA4 you have to create a data stream otherwise you don't have the tracking code where to send the data.

For the cookie policy the legal interpretations may differ, in any case the user's IP in GA4 is always anonymized therefore a practice is to insert GA cookies as technicians (necessary) in the cookie policy (because they have no identification power). Others, to be on the safe side, place them as static cookies.